# JPA Table Cannot Be Resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have a JPA Entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER", schema="APP")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue 
    private long id; 
    private String name;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public User() {
        super();
    }   
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String nam) {
        this.name = nam;
    }   


}
```

I try to generate the related table in this way:
[image]

But I get this:
[image]

I think this can be relevant:

[image]

I can't see why it creates a schema USER and a table SEQUENCE within it:
[image]

Comment: Depending on the database, `USER` may be a reserved work. You seem to use Derby. It is a reserved word in Derby: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefkeywords29722.html. Try naming your table differently.

Comment: you are right! post the answer

Comment: Or specify the table name as quoted ("User", with single or double quotes). Or use a JPA provider that auto-quotes any SQL keywords for you so you don't have to frig about with such things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the database, USER may be a reserved word. You seem to use Derby. It *is* a reserved word in Derby:

> https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefkeywords29722.html.

Try naming your table differently.